# PyTorch lists as indexes instead of slice notation

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am working with BERT context vectors and I am trying to extract specific layer activations for specific tokens. I can extract sequential layers fine using ":" slice notation but I want specific layers given by a list (or some other method) e.g. first and fourth layers only.

```py
# (num_target_tokens, num_tokens_in_sequence, num_bert_layers, size_of_bert_vector)
example = torch.randn([3, 12, 13, 768])
indices = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 10], [2, 11]])

a = example[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1], -4:]
b = example[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1], 1:5]

# (num_target_tokens, num_specified_layers, size_of_bert_vector)
a.shape
>> torch.Size([3, 4, 768])
b.shape
>> torch.Size([3, 4, 768])

# Desired output shape: torch.Size([3, 4, 768])
c = example[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1], [1, 3, 5, 7]] # Desired usage
>> shape mismatch: indexing tensors could not be broadcast together with shapes [3], [3], [4]
```

Is there some elegant way to achieve this with indexing or will I need to split my tensors to achieve this result.